# Text processing in a playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm working on an ansible playbook to start our provisioning process, and I'm accepting user input for a number of variables, including hostname and ip. Once I have ip, I can calculate the gateway which I need to give to Cobbler, but I can't seem to work out how to turn the ip into a gateway within the constrictions of an ansible playbook. It sure seems like this ought to be possible, but I'm just not seeing it.

Actually, the only solution I've come up with so far is to create a local file using a template (which seems to allow more complex templating than just filters) and then use local_action to execute that file. But is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need to do is change something like 192.168.123.234 to 192.168.1.1 then something along the following would work:

```
vars:
  ip: '192.168.123.234'

tasks:
- local_action: shell echo {{ ip }} | sed -e 's/\.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.$/.1.1/'
  register: result

- local_action: debug msg={{ result.stdout }}
```

It's a little ugly but it gets the job done.

Comment: I was wondering if I would have to delve into creating a custom module for this. Would that be cleaner, or is that then overkill?

Comment: Although Ansible modules can be written in pretty much any language all the tutorials, included modules, etc. are written in Python.  There's a quick tutorial on writing them (in Python) [here](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_modules.html). In a nutshell, parameters are passed on the command line and results passed back as JSON via stdout. So writing a custom module might end up being a little cleaner, especially if you need to do significantly more than what I outlined above.

Comment: I'm working through doing that, because I realized a had a number of steps that could be consolidated into one logical one. Thanks for the help, though, I'm sure I'll put that trick to use in the future!

Comment: @Bret Any success in developing this module? I would also be interested.